# Why not create Foreign Key with getters and setters in sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm new to sequelize. I have implemented setters and getters to my model and then I added a foreign key but it is not created. It is only created when I remove the getters and setters.
I'm doing something wrong?

Model Zone

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
const Zone = sequelize.define('Zone', {
    zone: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
},{
    getterMethods: {
        zone: () => {
            return this.getDataValue('zone');
        }
    },
    setterMethods: {
        zone: (zone) => {
            return this.setDataValue('zone', zone);
        }
    }
},{
    classMethods: {
        associate: (models) => {
            Zone.hasMany(models.Client, {
                foreignKey: 'zone_id',
                as: 'zoneFk'
            });
        },
    },
});
return Zone;
};
```

Model Client

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const Client = sequelize.define('Client',{
      //atributtes...
}, {
    classMethods: {
        associate: (models) => {
            Client.belongsTo(models.Zone, {
                foreignKey: 'zone_id',
                onDelete: 'CASCADE'
            });
        },
    },
});
return Client;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

first argument of sequelize.define takes definition of columns like

```
 sequelize.define('Zone', {
    zone: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    zone_id: {
         type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
         primaryKey: true,
         //autoIncrement:true
     }
},
```

also here zone_id must be unique/primary key so that it match a unique value.